# changing the menu toggle name for the title of the post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making my first steps learning to code. I made some courses in Codeacademy and now I decided to continue learning while I build a wordpress child theme.

The thing is that I have a menu toggle. It's a button called menu:

```
<button id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></button>
```

What I'm trying to do is to replace the name "Menu" and give it the name of the actual page or post title.

I tried to make this but it doesn't work:

```
<button id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( '<?php the_title(); ?>', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></button>
```

Do you have some suggestion? Maybe the solution is something more complex than this that I try to imagine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the awesome world of PHP and WordPress development

The opening php tag ( `<?php` ) is used already in button, using it again inside `__()` function would result in an error...

Also, `the_title()` would echo the title, not return it which will not pass the value to `__` translation function...
Best thing to do is to remove `__()` translation function altogether so that your code looks like this...

```
<button id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle"><?php the_title(); ?></button>
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps a lot